# Compilation errors when trying to include files from boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to use boost property tree in a project of mine, but when I try to build the components that use property tree, I get the following compilation errors:

```
[  6%] Built target distro_core_app_objects
[ 10%] Built target distro_core_utility_objects
[ 13%] Built target distro_core_utility_static
[ 20%] Built target distro_core_error_objects
[ 23%] Built target distro_core_error_static
[ 26%] Built target distro_core_app_static
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target distro_core_config_objects
[ 30%] Building CXX object core/config/CMakeFiles/distro_core_config_objects.dir/Configurations.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/boost/multi_index_container.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp:21,
                 from /home/nmcurtis/distro/core/config/Node.hpp:3,
                 from /home/nmcurtis/distro/core/config/Configurations.hpp:3,
                 from /home/nmcurtis/distro/core/config/Configurations.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::detail::allocator::rebinder<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >::result<boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > > > >’:
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp:133:49:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::allocator::compliant_allocator_rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:31:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::detail::allocator::partial_std_allocator_rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > > > >, boost::detail::allocator::compliant_allocator_rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp:139:8:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::allocator::rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index_node<boost::multi_index::detail::index_node_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/multi_index_container.hpp:84:7:   required from ‘class boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:58:13:   required from ‘struct boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs’
/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:180:22:   required from ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::basic_ptree() [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Data = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; KeyCompare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
/home/nmcurtis/distro/core/config/Configurations.hpp:49:30:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp:125:31: error: no class template named ‘rebind’ in ‘class std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’
  125 |           rebind<Type>::other other;
      |                               ^~~~~
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp: In instantiation of ‘struct boost::detail::allocator::rebinder<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >::result<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’:
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp:133:49:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::allocator::compliant_allocator_rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:60:31:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::eval_if_c<false, boost::detail::allocator::partial_std_allocator_rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, boost::detail::allocator::compliant_allocator_rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/detail/allocator_utilities.hpp:139:8:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::allocator::rebind_to<std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >’
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/detail/index_base.hpp:68:47:   required from ‘class boost::multi_index::detail::index_base<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp:115:7:   required from ‘class boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_index<boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<2, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >, boost::mpl::v_item<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na>, 0>, boost::multi_index::detail::ordered_non_unique_tag>’
/usr/include/boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp:73:7:   required from ‘class boost::multi_index::detail::sequenced_index<boost::multi_index::detail::nth_layer<1, std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >, boost::mpl::vector0<mpl_::na> >’
/usr/include/boost/multi_index_container.hpp:84:7:   required from ‘class boost::multi_index::multi_index_container<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, boost::multi_index::indexed_by<boost::multi_index::sequenced<>, boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<boost::multi_index::tag<boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs::by_name, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, boost::multi_index::member<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, &std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::first>, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na, mpl_::na>, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > > >’
/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:58:13:   required from ‘struct boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::subs’
/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:180:22:   required from ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<Key, Data, KeyCompare>::basic_ptree() [with Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; Data = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; KeyCompare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >]’
/home/nmcurtis/distro/core/config/Configurations.hpp:49:30:   required from here
```

I'm not sure why this would be happening. I'm compiling with gcc-11.3.0, using c++-20, and boost 1.58. Is it possible there is some versioning issue here?

Comment: I'm suspecting it is a versioning issue, trying boost 1.80 beta.

Comment: Might/might not be a versioning issue. Can you show how the project is built and some sample code, maybe this `Configurations.hpp`.